# Getting info about selected posts using one WP_Query

Tags: php, posts, wp-query

I'm currently working on displaying recent posts in 'masonry grid'. Because of multiple issues I came out with the idea of displaying pre-defined rows of that grid (due to designed layout).

First I did all that without dynamic content (posts). Then I tried to get WP_Query to work. But instead of displaying multiple posts in one row, I'm displaying one multiplied post per each row.

I already did "more posts" button - and it reveals content as described above too.

I suppose that `prev_post()` method may be wrong for that case, but I didn't found in Codex anything that might be better.

Below I attach part of code & screens to better show both problem and desired effect.

```php
$wpb_all_query = new WP_Query([
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => '4',
]);

if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) {
        ob_start();
        ?>

        <div class="list_row three_col">
            <div class="column column_1_3">
                <?php
                $wpb_all_query->the_post();  //1 - the newest post 
                get_template_part('partials/list-single-post-masonry');
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column column_1_3">
                <?php
                $wpb_all_query->prev_post(); //2 - older older than 1
                get_template_part('partials/list-single-post-masonry');

                $wpb_all_query->prev_post(); //3 - older than 2
                get_template_part('partials/list-single-post-masonry');
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="column column_1_3">
                <?php
                $wpb_all_query->prev_post(); //4 - older than 3
                get_template_part('partials/list-single-post-masonry');
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php
        $generated_content = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
}

return $generated_content;
```

[SCREEN no.1 - how it's looking now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v6Ku.png)

[SCREEN no.2 - how it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UuDTR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$wpb_all_query->prev_post()` to `$wpb_all_query->the_post()`.

Class [`WP_Query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#methods) **does not have** `prev_post()` method, it has the `next_post()` method, which takes the next post from the results (set up `post` member of WP_Query object), but it does not set the global  variable. To reach for the data of the current post, you must use `$wpb_all_query->post` (eg. *$wpb_all_query->post->post_name* ) or use `$wpb_all_query->setup_postdata()` to set the global variable `$post`.

`$wpb_all_query->the_post()` is equivalent to:

```
$wpb_all_query->next_post();
$wpb_all_query->setup_postdata();
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thx!